# How to I constract a grammar that generates this language ? (Grammar of type 0)

Tags: automation, grammar, context-free-grammar, computation-theory, chomsky-hierarchy

How do I constract the grammar of this language: {a^(i^2), i >0} ?

I recognize that it is a grammar of type 0 according to Chomsky classification.
I'm trying to find a relation between the algorithm that generates i^2 and the grammar, but couldn't find anything.

Any help please?